# How can I use a variable to switch between two formula in a shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, shader

I made a Shader and I want it to work in the other direction. As the coordinate system is from 0 to 1, I need to reverse the output of a function but I can't wrap my head around it. It boils down to this "simple" problem:

In one case I want it to be y = 1 - x and in the other y = x. How can I use a variable `a` such that if `a == 0` then `y = 1 - x` or if `a == 1` then `y = x`? Without using branching.

Comment: Not really sure what your question is trying to get at... But does it help to suggest `y = a*x + (1-a)*(1-x)`  then you can change a=0 or a=1?

Comment: @Ruzihm Thats it! Thank you so so much! If you write your answer ill mark it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `y = a * x + (1 - A) * (1 - x)` then you can have `A` change between 0 or 1 to switch between `y = 1 - x` and `y = x`.